# d3.js json http authentication issue (no data receive)

Tags: javascript, authentication, d3.js

I try to get json data for D3.js on a server that request an authentication. 
After many search on google I didn't find any answer to my problem. 
I get an error : XMLHttpRequest { readyState=4, timeout=0, withCredentials=false, more...} see details below.
Before any comment regarding security (the scripts runs on an isolated network with no connection to the internet)

my d3.js code is :

```
function make_base_auth(user, password) {
var tok = user + ':' + password;
var hash = btoa(tok);
return "Basic " + hash;

d3.json("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/request-json").header("Authenticate", make_base_auth("login","password").get(function(error,data){

if (error) {
    console.log(error);
}else {
    console.log(data);
  }

... rest of code...
```

error details :

```
XMLHttpRequest { readyState=4, timeout=0, withCredentials=false, more...}

DONE
    4
HEADERS_RECEIVED
    2
LOADING
    3
OPENED
    1
UNSENT
    0
getmozAnon
    false
mozBackgroundRequest
    false
getmozSystem
    false
onloadend
    null
ontimeout
    null
getreadyState
    4
getresponse
    ""
getresponseText
    ""
responseType
    ""
getresponseXML
    null
getstatus
    0
getstatusText
    ""
timeout
    0
getupload
    XMLHttpRequestUpload { onloadstart=null, onprogress=null, onabort=null, more...}
withCredentials
    false
abort
    abort()
addEventListener
    addEventListener()
dispatchEvent
    dispatchEvent()
getAllResponseHeaders
    getAllResponseHeaders()
getResponseHeader
    getResponseHeader()
onerror
    u()
onload
    u()
onprogress
    function()
open
    open()
overrideMimeType
    overrideMimeType()
removeEventListener
    removeEventListener()
send
    send()
sendAsBinary
    sendAsBinary()
setRequestHeader
    setRequestHeader()
__proto__
    XMLHttpRequestPrototype { UNSENT=0, OPENED=1, HEADERS_RECEIVED=2, more...}
```

Thank for your help
Guillaume

Comment: Is this a cross-site request? Is the domain of `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/request-json` different to the domain that you loaded your script from?

Answer (score 1):

1. The http basic header should be 'Authorization' and not 'Authenticate'.
   Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication.
2. If you are calling a URL from a different server than your web page, make sure your server supports CORS.